# cscope setting with vim

Tags: linux, vim, cscope

I am trying to incorporate cscope settings with vim to get an IDE like functionality.
I am using the popular cscope_maps.vim file http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim
in order to get these settings.I copied these settings to my vimrc file and and tried to source it.
This is the result I get for the same.

```
syntax error near unexpected token `'cscope''
```

Does this mean my Vim(version 7.0) doesnt support cscope ??
How do I resolve this.
I also observe that my ctags settings  works perfectly
Thanks
Satwik

Comment: `echo has("cscope")` should return 1. Also you should put that file in `~/.vim/plugin` instead of your vimrc. I reccomend upgrading your copy of vim we are on version 7.4. 7.0 is from 2006

Comment: Hi this is what I get when I echo

Comment: bash-3.2$ echo has("cscope")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Run that in vim not bash

Comment: Hi realized it I ran that on vim and I got the value 1.

Comment: Im going to guess your problem was that you sourced the vimrc in bash? Other than this you should probably post the output you get.

Comment: I guessed it too now.I sourced it from vim and looks like its in place now.Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from your shell, not Vim. Compare:

```
$ if has("cscope")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"cscope"'
```

with

```
:cscope
E492: Not an editor command: cscope
```

You need to source the plugin inside Vim!